# error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword

Tags: installation

After installing bitcoin on CentOS/AWS, an error occurs when connecting with cli.

```
$ bitcoind -daemon -conf=/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
Bitcoin server starting
$ bitcoin-cli getbalance
error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword
```

The following is bitcoin.conf.

```
mainnet = 1
txindex = 1
server = 1
rest = 1
rpcuser = a
rpcpassword = a
rpcport = 8332
```

Comment: The following is displayed when executing bitcoind.
----------
Binding RPC on address ::1 port 8332 failed.
----------
Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
----------

Comment: `-conf=/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` is unusual as it suggests you're keeping the `.bitcoin` outside your `/home` folder. If that's a mistake, it would explain why bitcoin-cli can't find the credentials - the conf file you're specifying doesn't exist. Are you sure you sure you don't mean `-conf=/home/<user>/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`?

Comment: Thank you for answering.I created bitcoin.conf with the following command. Is that wrong?
mkdir ~/.bitcoin
vi ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

Comment: If that's two commands then they do seem right. However your question says you used `/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` which is not the same as `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`. The first says start in the root of your file system, the second - with a tilde '~' - says to start in your home folder.

Answer (score -1):

In case you changed your `/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service` make sure you run

```
 sudo systemctl stop bitcoind
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl start bitcoind
```

to apply the changes.

Comment: While this advice may be useful, the question doesn't ask anything about systemd or with changing systemd service files.