# Please tell me the procedure for installing bitcoin full node in CUI on CentOS

Tags: installation

I am really sorry, please teach.
Please tell me the procedure for installing bitcoin full node in CUI on CentOS.
Currently I installed using the following procedure, but I got an error in RPC authentication.

1.
`$ sudo yum install wget`

2.
`$ sudo wget https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.17.1/bitcoin-0.17.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

3.
`$ sudo wget https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.17.1/SHA256SUMS.asc`

4.
`$ sudo wget https://bitcoin.org/laanwj-releases.asc`

5.
`$ sudo gpg --import laanwj-releases.asc`

6.
`$ sudo tar -zxvf bitcoin-0.17.1-x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz`

7.
`$ sudo install -m 0755 -o USER_NAME -g root -t /usr/local/bin bitcoin-0.17.1/bin/*`

8.
`$ mkdir ~/.bitcoin`

9.
`$ vi ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

10. Enter the following with vi and save.

```
mainnet = 1
txindex = 1
server = 1
rest = 1
rpcuser = a
rpcpassword = a
rpcport = 8332
```

11.
`$ cd /DATA_DIR`

12.
`$ sudo mkdir bitcoin`

13.
`$ sudo chmod -R 777 bitcoin/`

14.
`$ bitcoind -daemon -datadir=/DATA_DIR/bitcoin -conf=/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

`Bitcoin server starting`

15.
`$ bitcoin-cli getbalance`

After this, the following URL error will occur.
[error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85705/error-authorization-failed-incorrect-rpcuser-or-rpcpassword)

`error: Authorization failed: Incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword`

Which procedure is wrong and how do I fix it?
I am really sorry, please teach.

Answer (score 1):

In your bitcoin.conf, remove the spaces before and after the equals (`=`) sign. I believe the conf file parser does not handle spaces well.

Also, your command has `-conf=/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`, but your conf file is at `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` so it is pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: As you say, I deleted the space before and after = and corrected the path specification when starting bitcoind, and RPC worked correctly. Thank you!
　bitcoind -daemon -datadir=/DATA_DIR/bitcoin -conf=/home/USER_DIR/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf